# Suspend and resume F# asynchronous workflows (Async<'T>)

Tags: f#, resume, suspend, async-workflow

Is there a general way to gain external control over the execution of an arbitrary asynchronous workflow, for suspension and resumption? Akin to a CancellationToken but more like a SuspendResumeToken where one could simply do things like:

```
let suspendResumeToken = new SuspendResumeToken()
Async.Start(longRunningAsync, suspendResumeToken=suspendResumeToken)
...
// meanwhile
async {
   do! suspendResumeToken.SuspendAsync()
   printfn "Suspended longRunningAsync!"
   do! suspendResumeToken.ResumeAsync()
   printfn "Resumed longRunningAsync!"
}
```

I could emulate the behavior for recursive or iterated functions, by checking such a token at every iteration or recursion step, but since async workflows have natural yield points, it would be natural to have that built-in, as a general way to control async scheduling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing something like your `SuspendResumeToken` is easily done using events. You can define an event, await it in the computation and then trigger it from the outside to resume the computation:

```
let suspendEvent = new Event<_>()
let awaitSuspendResume () = suspendEvent.Publish |> Async.AwaitEvent

let longRunningAsync () = async {
   do! awaitSuspendResume ()
   printfn "Suspended longRunningAsync!"
   do! awaitSuspendResume ()
   printfn "Resumed longRunningAsync!"
}

Async.Start(longRunningAsync())

suspendEvent.Trigger() // Run this multiple times to make a step
```

There is no way to get this automatically at yield-points in `async`, but you could define your own computation builder which is exactly like `async`, except that it inserts the check in the `Bind` operation (and possibly some other places - you'd have to think about where exactly you want to do this):

```
let suspendEvent = new Event<_>()
let awaitSuspendResume () = suspendEvent.Publish |> Async.AwaitEvent

type SuspendAsyncBuilder() = 
  // Custom 'Bind' with the extra check
  member x.Bind(a:Async<'T>, f:'T -> Async<'R>) : Async<'R> = 
    async { 
      let! av = a
      do! awaitSuspendResume()
      return! f av }
  // All other operations just call normal 'async'
  // (you will need to add many more here!)
  member x.Zero() = async.Zero()

let sasync = SuspendAsyncBuilder()

let longRunningAsync () = sasync {
   do! Async.Sleep(0)
   printfn "Suspended longRunningAsync!"
   do! Async.Sleep(0)
   printfn "Resumed longRunningAsync!"
}

Async.Start(longRunningAsync())
suspendEvent.Trigger()
```

Note that this only checks around `!` operations like `do!` so I had to insert a `Sleep` in the example to make it work.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you Thomas. :-)